# Neo4j 3.4 upgrade--DB not starting

Tags: neo4j

After attempting to update to Neo4j 3.4 the DB fails to start. Here is the log:

> > WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with administrative rights.  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
> >     2018-05-23 16:17:25.306+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.0 ========
> >     2018-05-23 16:17:25.365+0000 INFO  Starting... 2018-05-23
> >     16:17:27.607+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics... 2018-05-23
> >     16:17:33.331+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at
> >     C:\Users\miz9013\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\metrics
> >     2018-05-23 16:17:34.349+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:11002.
> >     2018-05-23 16:17:35.937+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting
> >     Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     Starting Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed:
> >     Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
> >       at
> >     com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
> >     Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
> >       ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
> >     C:\Users\miz9013\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\data\databases\graph.db
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:39)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 5 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
> >     Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@787178b1' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
> >       ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/security/SecurityContext;   at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:290)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:242)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:78)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:323)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext     at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 21 more
> >     2018-05-23 16:17:35.951+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by
> >     request WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with
> >     administrative rights.  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
> >     2018-05-23 19:10:38.733+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.0 ========
> >     2018-05-23 19:10:38.799+0000 INFO  Starting... 2018-05-23
> >     19:10:42.536+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics... 2018-05-23
> >     19:10:48.101+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at
> >     C:\Users\miz9013\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\metrics
> >     2018-05-23 19:10:48.848+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:11002.
> >     2018-05-23 19:10:50.174+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting
> >     Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     Starting Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed:
> >     Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
> >       at
> >     com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
> >     Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
> >       ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
> >     C:\Users\miz9013\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\data\databases\graph.db
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:39)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 5 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
> >     Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@787178b1' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
> >       ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/security/SecurityContext;   at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:290)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:242)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:78)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:323)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext     at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 21 more
> >     2018-05-23 19:10:50.176+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by
> >     request WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with
> >     administrative rights.  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
> >     2018-05-23 19:11:19.679+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.0 ========
> >     2018-05-23 19:11:19.726+0000 INFO  Starting... 2018-05-23
> >     19:11:22.465+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics... 2018-05-23
> >     19:11:28.419+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\metrics
> >     2018-05-23 19:11:29.145+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:11002.
> >     2018-05-23 19:11:31.478+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting
> >     Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     Starting Neo4j failed: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed:
> >     Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
> >       at
> >     com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
> >     Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
> >     'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3af236d0' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
> >       ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
> >     C:\Roaming\Neo4j
> >     Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-5aba9bf6-8425-4e66-a065-6a5987cff891\current\data\databases\graph.db
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:39)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 5 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
> >     Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@787178b1' was
> >     successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> >     cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext".  at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
> >       ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/security/SecurityContext;   at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
> >     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:290)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ReflectiveProcedureCompiler.java:242)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:90)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:78)
> >       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:323)
> >       at
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
> >       ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.neo4j.kernel.api.security.SecurityContext     at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 21 more
> >     2018-05-23 19:11:31.482+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by
> >     request

Comment: Have you also updated your plugins ?

Comment: Yes. I ended up creating a new DB and copying the files into the new DB. Not ideal but it worked...

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be an incompatible version of a plugin like APOC, see GitHub repository of APOC for more information: [https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/734](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/734/)